# g++ auto and typename keywords in function return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, c++14

When I [using SFINAE with functions/function members](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80c25fdd0d4f2930) in following manner:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

struct X {};

struct A
{

    template< typename T >
    auto
    f(T && x)
    -> std::enable_if< std::is_same< T, X >::value >::type
    {
        return x;
    }

};

int main()
{ 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get an error:

```
main.cpp:14:8: error: expected type-specifier
     -> std::enable_if< std::is_same< T, X >::value >::type
        ^
main.cpp:14:8: error: expected initializer
```

thereby I should prepend enabler with `typename` keyword. But there are no ambiguities here at all: as I now only type expected after `->`. Another hint to think so is **Qt Creator's** underliyng of `typename` keyword in such context.

Is this **G++** bug? Or there is claim to `typename` for such context in C++11?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: @DanielFrey I could not find a similar context in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any time you access a dependent type name (a type name nested inside of an expression that depends on a template parameter), you need to use the `typename` keyword. In this context, I'm pretty sure that you're right that there's no ambiguity, but if I remember correctly this is just how the language is defined.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A base-class-specifier as an exception, the `typename` is not needed there.

Answer (score 5):

> But there are no ambiguities here at all: as I now only type expected after ->

That's not really how it works.

Similarly, only a type is expected in the following declaration:

```
T::some_member x;
```

but you still need `typename` when `T` is dependent, to satisfy certain phases of compilation.

The compiler doesn't *know* that this is a declaration (before deciding whether or not it's valid) until it can see that you have a `->` followed by a *type*. So if it doesn't know you have a type, it doesn't know there's "no ambiguity". It's a chicken-and-egg problem.